# Is it possible to backup only one of Redis' databases?

Tags: redis

I want to have 2 (perhaps more later) databases on Redis with different backup requirements.  DB 0 for ephemeral data and DB 1 for durable data.  For example, DB 0 contains statistics across multiple players, (e.g., high scores), which I don't mind losing because they are updated constantly anyway, while DB 1 contains each individual player's top 5 scores (which I don't want to lose if the server crashes).  I want to backup DB 1 only.  Is this possible?  I think AOF is what I need, but I don't want to "pollute" it with transactions in DB 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. Redis' numbered/shared databases are a poor man's namespacing and share everything - configuration, server process and backups.

Comment: Thanks @Itamar-haber.   So the only way to do what I want is to have 2 redis instances?

Comment: Exactly - divide and conquer.